# Using UISegmentedControl in Xcode as RadioButtons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I have just recently started teaching myself Objective-C and iphone/ipad development.  With my only prior experience in coding involving Java/Android, I have been having some problems with this new language.

I am trying to use `UISegmentedControl` in this app to decide which view will be shown when the "members" button is pressed.  I do this by grabbing the current selected text from the `UISegmentedControl`, named "`memberPicker`", when the "members" button is pressed and then check if it is either `@"Current"` or `@"Alumni"` to decide what view is shown.

[image]

This function appears to be working correctly, however, when I click the "Alumni" button in the UISegmentedControl, the app crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainPageViewController MemberSegmentedControl:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7557250'
```

I believe my problem is with declaring or setting my UISegmentedControl properly, I understand it can take an array and ect. but I only need it to alternate between selecting Current or Alumni, and then my "members" button will do the rest. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Here is the code from my .m view

```
#import "MainPageViewController.h"
#import "AKPsiAppViewController.h"

@interface MainPageViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) UISegmentedControl *memberPicker;

@end

@implementation MainPageViewController

@synthesize memberPicker = _memberPicker;


- (IBAction)membersButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if([[self.memberPicker titleForSegmentAtIndex: self.memberPicker.selectedSegmentIndex] isEqualToString:@"Current"])
   {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Current Member Segue" sender:self]; 
   }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting means that you are calling the IBAction/function **MemberSegmentedControl:** which does not exist in the .m file. Maybe you had previously created this function and connected it with ***Value Changed*** of UISegmentedControl but you did not write its implemention (in .m file). Maybe you have deleted this but the connection still exists. To check this, please follow the following steps.

> > 1. Open **Interface Builder**.
> > 2. Click on the **UISegmentedControl**.
> > 3. Open **Connections Inspector** (Click on View Menu, Click on Utilities and then Click on "Show Connections Inspector". Alternatively you can press ***Command+Options+6***)
> > 4. Under *Sent Events*, check if there is any of the events (especially ***Value Changed***) connected to **"File owner's MemberSegmentedControl:"**. If yes, then remove it by clicking on the x button and then try again.

If your problem doesn't get resolved, please do the following

> > 1. Share a screenshot of the Interface Builder file (XIB file)
> > 2. Share the header file (.h file)

Comment: And Eureka! Problem solved.  I knew it would be an easy fix but its folks like yourself that help smack me over the head and show me what's what.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have connected the `UISegmentedControl` in Interface Builder to a `IBOutlet` named `MemberSegmentedControl` that you later removed in the `@interface` of your class. Check the connections to the `UISegmentedControl` in Interface Builder if there is not an additional connection besides the `memberPicker`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That was indeed the problem, but Nasir beat you to it. +1 for taking the time to help me out though!

Comment: Thanks! Check again though! My answer came 2 hours before his!